# Word VBA table - copy formatted cell contents but not table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy content of Word table cells (formatted text, bullet points, tables, images) and paste them into an output docx file. Unfortunately code below copies the whole cell, so that an undesired table is created in output file.

```
With outputApp.Selection
    dbDoc.Tables(1).Cell(tableRow, 3).Range.Copy
    .Paste
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to transform tables in an output document into their formatted content, while preserving nested tables. Afterwards I remove indentation of the content and previously nested tables, because it is not needed anymore after getting rid of the main table.

Still hoping to find a cleaner and more efficient solution.

```
For Each table In outputDoc.Tables        
    table.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, NestedTables:=False
Next table

With outputDoc.Content.ParagraphFormat
    .LeftIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0)
End With

For Each table In outputDoc.Tables
    table.Rows.LeftIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0)
Next table
```